# Thread issue in socket Programming

Tags: linux, multithreading, sockets, pthreads

I have the following codes..

**server.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "./../linux.h"
#include "./tcp.h"
#include <pthread.h>

static int clients = 0;
static int* memptr = NULL;

void serve(void*);

int* push(int* memptr, int nsfd) {
  clients++;
  if (clients == 1)
     memptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * clients);
  else
     memptr = (int*)realloc(memptr, sizeof(int) * clients);
  memptr[clients - 1] = nsfd;
 return memptr;
 }



 int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    pthread_t thread[2];
    int threadCount = 0;

   if (argc != 3){
     printf("\nUsage: ./server port_number maximum_clients\n");
     return 1;
   }
   static struct sockaddr_in sock, sock_client;
   int len, new_sock_fd;
   int sock_fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if (sock_fd == -1){
     perror("socket");
     exit(1);
   }
  sock.sin_family = PF_INET;
  sock.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
  sock.sin_addr.s_addr  = inet_addr("0.0.0.0");
  len = sizeof(sock);
  if ( bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&sock, len) == -1){
    perror("bind");
    exit(1);
  }
  if ( listen(sock_fd, atoi(argv[2])) == -1){
    perror("listen");
    exit(1);
  }

  while(1) {
     new_sock_fd = accept(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&sock_client, (socklen_t *)&len);
     memptr = push(memptr, new_sock_fd);

     if (new_sock_fd == -1){
       perror("accept");
       exit(1);
     }

  pthread_create(&(thread[threadCount]), NULL, (void*)&serve, (void *)&new_sock_fd);
  pthread_join(thread[threadCount++], NULL);
  printf("threadCount  = %d\n", threadCount);

     sleep(1);
   }
return 0;
 }



 void serve(void* fd){
   int* new_sock_fd = (int*)fd;
   Packet packet;
   while(1){
      bzero(&packet, sizeof(packet));
      read(*new_sock_fd , &packet, sizeof(packet));
      printf("%d\n", *new_sock_fd);
      //printf("recipientId = %d\n", packet.recipientId);
      // printf("message = %s\n", packet.data);
      write(memptr[packet.recipientId - 1], packet.data, 1024);
     }
    pthread_exit(0);
    }
```

and the **tcp.h** looks like

```
       #ifndef __TCP_H__
       #     define __TCP_H__

       typedef struct {

            int recipientId;    // this is the reciever ID
            char data[1024];           // this is the main data part

           }Packet;


       #endif /* __TCP_H__ */
```

and each **client.h** looks like this

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "./../linux.h"
 #include "./tcp.h"
 #include <pthread.h>

 void print(void);
 void scan(void);
 int sock_fd;
 int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 if (argc != 3){
     printf("\nUsage: ./client port_number server_ip\n");
     return 1;
  }
 static struct sockaddr_in sock;
 int len;
 pthread_t thread1, thread2;
 sock_fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 if (sock_fd == -1){
   perror("socket");
   exit(1);
 }
 sock.sin_family = PF_INET;
 sock.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
 sock.sin_addr.s_addr  = inet_addr(argv[2]);
 len = sizeof(sock);
 if ( connect(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&sock , len) == -1 ){
   perror("connect");
   exit(1);
 }

 pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, (void*)&print, NULL);
 pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, (void*)&scan, NULL);

 pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
 pthread_join(thread2, NULL);


 return 0;
}

 void print(){
   char messege[1024];
   while(1){
   if (read(sock_fd, messege, 1024) == -1){
     perror("read");
     return;
   }
   printf("messege = %s\n", messege);
  }
 pthread_exit(0);
 }

  void scan(void){
    Packet packet;
    while(1){
      printf("Enter the reciver ID: ");
      scanf("%d", &packet.recipientId);
      printf("Enter the data: ");
      scanf("%s", packet.data);
      if ( write(sock_fd, &packet, sizeof(packet)) == -1) {
        perror("read");
        return;
      }
   }
   pthread_exit(0);
  }
```

Now the problems are

1. when I am running the server & the in 2 terminals, 2 clients after each client is accepted `threadCount` should be printed at the server end but it is not printing. It means the execution stops/skips after the first `pthread_join` but **WHY** ??
2. After connecting two threads, when I sent the data from 1st client to the 1st client itself, it works but not from the 1st client to the 2nd client..rather it is sending to the server terminal window. **WHY ??**
3. When sent from the second client nothing works ( sending itself or client 1)..**WHY??**

Please help..And thanks for patiently reading all the codes above.

Comment: `pthread_join(thread[threadCount++], NULL);` will be looking for `thread[1]`, while you're actually trying to wait for `thread[0]`.  Why do you increment here?

Comment: Why it will look for thread[1]...it is a post incremental operator...so it will look for thread[0]

Comment: Yup - you're right.  I need more caffeine.  Sorry about that!

Comment: Hint: Starting and then immediately joining a thread is pointless.

Comment: Sorry but I am more interested in solution than hint now.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a byte stream protocol, not a message protocol. You are calling TCP functions and expecting them to send or receive messages. They don't. If you want to send or receive messages, you have to implement a message protocol, write functions that send and receive messages, and then call those functions.

```
if (read(sock_fd, messege, 1024) == -1){
  perror("read");
  return;
}
printf("messege = %s\n", messege);
```

This call to `printf` is a disaster. The `%s` format specifier is for C-style strings, not arbitrary chunks of bytes received from a byte stream. For the most obvious way to see how bad this is, consider this --- how should `printf` decide how many bytes to print? You threw away the value `read` returned after you compared it to -1, so you have no idea how many bytes you received.

I'm sure there are other issues with your code, but the fact that the fundamental design is broken makes it not worth fixing those issues. Instead, design a message protocol and implement that.